# AdMob not getting real ads in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am working for Admob in Android and I got success in getting test ad. But When I Change My Test UnitId To To Live UnitID something like this "/5479/ctv.abcd.ca/myid" I am getting the warning like "is your unit id correct ?". and also i commented the lines for adding test devices. but still i am not seeing any real adds.

Any Ideas..... Any Better Solution..

```
    LinearLayout lladView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.addmob, null);
    AdView adView = (AdView) lladView.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and my xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="/5479/ctv.abcd.ca/myid"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be providing the wrong `adUnitId`. You have to specify your AdMob publisher ID that can be obtained from the AdMob Sites & Apps -> [Your App Name] -> Manage Settings. 
[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your reply.  is there is any difference between unit id and publisher id? and also any limitations for publisher ID.

Comment: The adUnitId expects the publisher ID to be specified, there is no difference. Check the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android. I have not understood what you mean by limitation for publisher ID.

Comment: actually i got my unitid something like this from my client **5479/ctv.abcd.ca/myid**. so i am bit confused wether publisher id and unit id are same or publisher id is something like a 15 digit number .

Comment: and now i am getting log messages like Request scenario: Online server request.
Received ad url: <url: "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net:80/gampad/ads?...<html content>..88etc     Ads(3717): Bad request
onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)

Comment: Please verify with your client that he/she is indeed using the AdMob, not any other advertising platform. Regarding the error, please post the complete logcat statements of the error you are receiving.

Comment: Request scenario: Online server request.


 Received ad url: <url: "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net:80/gampad/ads?seq_num=52&u_w=600&msid=com.rds.android.hockey&cap=m&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1&bas_off=0&net=wi&hl=en&gnt=0&carrier&u_audio=1&kw&u_sd=1&mv=8016014.com.android.vending&isu=B0B0F8691404CE318A8E8CD89334A953&cipa=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=976&bas_on=0&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=300&url=10.android.com.rds.android.hockey.adsenseformobileapps.com&gdfp_req=1&markup=html&m_ast=afmajs&impl=ifr&correlator=4153884656623999&iu=%2F5479%2Fctv.rdsapp.ca%2Fhockey&

Comment: sz=320x50&kw_type=broad&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&admob_cust_params=preqs%253D51%2526u_w%253D600%2526msid%253Dcom.rds.android.hockey%2526js%253Dafma-sdk-a-v6.2.1%2526hl%253Den%2526u_audio%253D1%2526u_sd%253D1%2526u_h%253D976%2526ptime%253D253606%2526u_so%253Dp%2526output%253Dhtml%2526region%253Dmobile_app%2526u_tz%253D300%2526caps%253DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=45" type: "xfp" afmaNotifyDt: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">


 Bad request

 onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.

Comment: I got Solution Rajesh. Thank you very much for you answer. actually my Publish Id is wrong.